# Problems implementing AES in CBC+CTS mode

Tags: aes, cbc

I'm trying to implement an AES cipher in CBC+CTS mode, but I'm unable to get the second last plaintext block to decrypt properly. I've attached my code, it's based on the steps listed under [CBC ciphertext stealing decryption using a standard CBC interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing) on Wikipedia.

```
void AES::encrypt(const char* src, char* dest, size_t length)
{
    //Check if the length is less than 1 block
    if (length < 16) {
        //Pad the data to a complete block with zeroes
        char paddedBlock[16];
        memcpy(paddedBlock, src, length);
        memset(paddedBlock + length, 0, 16 - length);

        //Encrypt the padded block, and return early
        encryptBlock(paddedBlock, dest);
        return;
    }

    //Encypt all of the complete blocks
    while (length >= 16) {
        //Encrypt the next block
        encryptBlock(src, dest);
        src += 16;
        dest += 16;
        length -= 16;
    }

    //Check if a partial block remains
    if (length > 0) {
        //Perform CTS processing on the partial block
        if (m_CipherMode == MODE_ECB) {
            //Rewind the destination pointer to the second last block
            dest -= 16;

            //Copy the leading bytes of the second last block to the last block
            memcpy(dest + 16, dest, length);

            //Assemble the last block
            char lastBlock[16];
            memcpy(lastBlock, src, length);
            memcpy(lastBlock + length, dest + length, 16 - length);

            //Encrypt the last block
            encryptBlock(lastBlock, dest);
        } else if (m_CipherMode == MODE_CBC) {
            //Rewind the destination pointer to the second last block
            dest -= 16;

            //Copy the leading bytes of the second last block to the last block
            memcpy(dest + 16, dest, length);

            //Pad the partial last block to a complete block with zeroes
            char lastBlock[16];
            memcpy(lastBlock, src, length);
            memset(lastBlock + length, 0, 16 - length);

            //Encrypt the last block
            encryptBlock(lastBlock, dest);
        }
    }
}

void AES::decrypt(const char* src, char* dest, size_t length)
{
    //Check if the length is less than 1 block
    if (length < 16) {
        //Nothing we can really do here...
        memcpy(dest, src, length);
        return;
    }

    //Decrypt all of the complete blocks
    while (length >= 16) {
        //Decrypt the next block
        decryptBlock(src, dest);
        src += 16;
        dest += 16;
        length -= 16;
    }

    //Check if a partial block remains
    if (length > 0) {
        //Perform CTS processing on the partial block
        if (m_CipherMode == MODE_ECB) {
            //Rewind the destination pointer to the second last block
            dest -= 16;

            //Assemble the last block
            char lastBlock[16];
            memcpy(lastBlock, src, length);
            memcpy(lastBlock + length, dest + length, 16 - length);

            //Copy the leading bytes of the second last block to the last block
            memcpy(dest + 16, dest, length);

            //Decrypt the last block
            decryptBlock(lastBlock, dest);
        } else if (m_CipherMode == MODE_CBC) {
            //Rewind the destination pointer to the second last block
            dest -= 16;

            //Assemble the second last block
            char secondLastBlock[16];
            memcpy(secondLastBlock, src, length);
            memcpy(secondLastBlock + length, dest + length, 16 - length);

            //Assemble the last block
            char lastBlock[16];
            memcpy(lastBlock, src - 16, 16);

            //Decrypt the last two blocks
            decryptBlock(secondLastBlock, dest);
            decryptBlock(lastBlock);
            memcpy(dest + 16, lastBlock, length);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `encryptBlock()` and `decryptBlock()` are performing the CBC chaining and unchaining.

### Update

Here is some example output to demonstrate the problem:

```
//AES-128 encryption key
const char key[16] = {
    0x2B, 0x7E, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xAE, 0xD2, 0xA6,
    0xAB, 0xF7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xCF, 0x4F, 0x3C
};

//C string "My awkward 55B test string to test ciphertext stealing"
const char inputPlaintext[55] = {
    //Block 1
    0x4D, 0x79, 0x20, 0x61, 0x77, 0x6B, 0x77, 0x61,
    0x72, 0x64, 0x20, 0x35, 0x35, 0x42, 0x20, 0x74,

    //Block 2
    0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x69,
    0x6E, 0x67, 0x20, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x74, 0x65,

    //Block 3
    0x73, 0x74, 0x20, 0x63, 0x69, 0x70, 0x68, 0x65,
    0x72, 0x74, 0x65, 0x78, 0x74, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74,

    //Block 4
    0x65, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x00
};

//Encrypted ciphertext
const char encryptedCiphertext[55] = {
    //Block 1
    0x40, 0x6A, 0x5D, 0x3A, 0xF5, 0x98, 0x9D, 0xEA,
    0x6E, 0x70, 0x33, 0xA5, 0x6E, 0xBE, 0xAC, 0x38,

    //Block 2
    0xBD, 0x3F, 0xB0, 0xE0, 0xF5, 0xB7, 0x07, 0xE6,
    0xAA, 0xF5, 0x01, 0xC7, 0xEF, 0x92, 0x28, 0x50,

    //Block 3
    0xAD, 0x88, 0xEC, 0x34, 0x3F, 0x7E, 0x02, 0xF1,
    0x12, 0xD0, 0x86, 0x7E, 0x67, 0xCA, 0x09, 0x6D,

    //Block 4
    0xE6, 0x87, 0x54, 0x14, 0xF6, 0xC5, 0x75
};

//Decrypted plaintext
const char decryptedPlaintext[55] = {
    //Block 1 - correct
    0x4D, 0x79, 0x20, 0x61, 0x77, 0x6B, 0x77, 0x61,
    0x72, 0x64, 0x20, 0x35, 0x35, 0x42, 0x20, 0x74,

    //Block 2 - correct
    0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x69,
    0x6E, 0x67, 0x20, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x74, 0x65,

    //Block 3 - garbage
    0x7C, 0x61, 0xE3, 0x6D, 0x00, 0xFB, 0x59, 0x8D,
    0xB9, 0x64, 0x2D, 0x38, 0x70, 0xAA, 0xB0, 0xD9,

    //Block 4 - correct
    0x65, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x00
};
```

Comment: Do you think it is a problem with the cryptography/CTS or with the programming? If the latter, this should be on StackOverflow.

Comment: I think it's a problem with my understanding of CTS and how it's layered on top of CBC. The programming will therefore be wrong as well.

Comment: when you say "I am unable to get the second [to] last plaintext block to decrypt properly", does that mean the last block also decrypts incorrectly? So it is really the last two blocks? Is the plaintext length a multiple of 16 or is padding involved?

Comment: The plaintext is not an even multiple of 16B, hence the reason CTS is being used. The last plaintext block (which is not a multiple of 16B) decrypts correctly.

Comment: I've added some example output to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by separating the CBC logic from the block encryption logic. Here is the revised code:

```
void AES::encrypt(const char* src, char* dest, size_t length)
{
    //TODO: Handle data lengths < 1 block!

    //Encrypt all of the data
    while (length > 0) {
        //Copy the next source block to the state array
        memcpy(m_State, src, 16);
        src += 16;
        length -= 16;

        //Perform CBC pre-processing if necessary
        if (m_CipherMode == MODE_CBC) {
            //XOR the state array with the carry vector
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                m_State[i] = m_State[i] ^ m_CarryVector[i];
        }

        //Encrypt the state array
        aesEncrypt();

        //Perform CBC post-processing if necessary
        if (m_CipherMode == MODE_CBC) {
            //Save the state array as the next carry vector
            memcpy(m_CarryVector, m_State, 16);
        }

        //Perform ciphertext stealing if the next block is a partial block
        if (length > 0 && length < 16) {
            //Copy the last partial source block to a temporary buffer (in case of in-place encryption)
            char temp[length];
            memcpy(temp, src, length);

            //Copy the leading bytes of the state array to the last partial destination block
            memcpy(dest + 16, m_State, length);

            //Copy the temporary buffer to the state array
            memcpy(m_State, temp, length);

            //Perform CBC processing if necessary
            if (m_CipherMode == MODE_CBC) {
                //Pad the state array with zeroes
                memset(m_State + length, 0, 16 - length);

                //XOR the state array with the carry vector
                for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                    m_State[i] = m_State[i] ^ m_CarryVector[i];
            }

            //Encrypt the state array
            aesEncrypt();
            length = 0;
        }

        //Copy the state array to the destination block
        memcpy(dest, m_State, 16);
        dest += 16;
    }
}

void AES::decrypt(const char* src, char* dest, size_t length)
{
    //TODO: Handle data lengths < 1 block!

    //Encrypt all of the data
    while (length > 0) {
        //Copy the next source block to the state array
        memcpy(m_State, src, 16);
        src += 16;
        length -= 16;

        //Decrypt the state array
        aesDecrypt();

        //Reverse ciphertext stealing if the next block is a partial block
        if (length > 0 && length < 16) {
            //Perform CBC processing if necessary
            if (m_CipherMode == MODE_CBC) {
                //XOR the state array with the last partial source block
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    m_State[i] = m_State[i] ^ src[i];
            }

            //Copy the last partial source block to a temporary buffer (in case of in-place decryption)
            char temp[length];
            memcpy(temp, src, length);

            //Copy the leading bytes of the state array to the last partial destination block
            memcpy(dest + 16, m_State, length);

            //Copy the temporary buffer to the state array
            memcpy(m_State, temp, length);

            //Decrypt the state array
            aesDecrypt();
            length = 0;
        }

        //Perform CBC processing if necessary
        if (m_CipherMode == MODE_CBC) {
            //XOR the state array with the carry vector
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                m_State[i] = m_State[i] ^ m_CarryVector[i];

            //Save the source block as the next carry vector
            memcpy(m_CarryVector, src - 16, 16);
        }

        //Copy the state array to the destination block
        memcpy(dest, m_State, 16);
        dest += 16;
    }
}
```